# Como usar um string vinda do banco de dados

Tags: php, json, string

Eu tenho a seguinte string salva no banco de dados.

```
{"key":"save","user":"1","season":"2016","week201549":{"bloco":"Microciclo","day05122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""},"day06122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""}},"week201550":{"bloco":"Microciclo","day07122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""},"day08122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""},"day09122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""},"day10122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""},"day11122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""},"day12122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""},"day13122015":{"z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""}},"week201551":{"bloco":"Microciclo","day14122015":
```

Só não descobri como utilizar ela, gostaria por exemplo, de pegar as informações **week201549->bloco**.
Já tentei json_decode e mais um monte de coisas e não da nada.

Não sei o que fazer, ou teria alguma outra maneira de salvar no banco de dados?

Comment: Olá, se entendi bem sua necessidade creio que este link pode te ajudar: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Comment: O json colocado na pergunta tem um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: E qual seria esse erro?

Comment: Joga essa string no jsonlint e mude a chamada para: `json_decode($str) or die(json_last_error_msg())`

Comment: Coloquei no jsonlint: json_decode($str) e retornou o seguinte Error: Parse error on line 1:
json_decode({ "key"
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: o jsonlint acusou algum erro?

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 1:
json_decode({ "key"
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
Source is on GitHub. Props to Douglas Crockford of JSON and JS Lint and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema.

Na hora de salvar no banco de dados coloquei um **mysqli_real_escape_string** e funcionou todo o resto.

Putz, e eu quebrando a cabeça achando que era problema no json.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `json_decode()` conforme a resposta do @Raylan, segue exemplo:

```
$stringBanco = '{
    "key":"save",
    "user":"1",
    "season":"2016",
    "week201549": {
        "bloco":"Microciclo",
        "day05122015":{     "z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""
            },
        "day06122015":{ "z1":"0","z2":"0","z3":"0","z4":"0","z5":"0","z6":"0","z7":"0","terrain":"Terreno","rpe":"7","elevation":"1861","fc":"140","time":"250","distance":"86","training":" ","color":""
            }
        }
    }';

$json = json_decode($stringBanco) or die(json_last_error_msg());

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($json->week201549);
echo '</pre>';
```

Obs: Abreviei o seu a sua `string` pois ela estava muito grande e incompleta

Comment: Ta dando erro de sintaxe, não estou entendo por que.

Comment: Provavelmente a string que esta salva no banco esta incorreta

Comment: Sim, alguma coisa vindo do banco de dados estava dando erro.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que o ideal seria quebrar essa string em entidades e atributos dentro do banco de dados, por exemplo "key", "user", "season" seriam atributos de uma entidade. Se isso não for possível, você pode tentar usar algo como a função split do java (ou alguma similar dependendo da linguagem que você está usando), ela quebra a string usando um caracter que você passa por parâmetro e joga isso em um vetor.

Por exemplo:

```
String frase = "{'key':'save','user':'1','season':";  
String array[] = new String[3];    
array = frase.split(":");
```

array[0] = {'key'

array[1] = 'save','user'

array[2] = '1','season'